# VB.NET: How to change setting on Click events

Tags: vb.net

Visual Studio with VB.net: If I create a copy of a button on the forms designer, the click event is added to the click event handler of the source button.

How do I change this behaviour ? I want the click event of the second button be wired to a totally new click handler code, not to the already existing one of the first button.

Comment: drill into the event - it did not hook #2 to #1...why do you think it did?  It gave the copy a new name and will provide new event handlers too

Comment: @Plutonix: Unfortunately, VS does wire a copy of the button to the same event handler. Try it in a brand new project - very easy to reproduce. So not sure why the downvote.

Comment: @Neolisk Doesnt do that on mine - old or new project.  1 handler per button (VS2005 and VS 2012)

Comment: @Plutonix: I figured it depends on user copy habits. See my answer.

Comment: @Neolisk thats actually a handy feature allows you to clone or copy a control

Comment: @Plutonix: To me clone or copy is the same thing. Do you have a reference on the naming of these features (official or not)?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to copy a button.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or same with right click menu). This will create a new button with a **new event handler**. Note that this new event handler is not created automatically, but will be created on button click in VS designer.
2. CTRL + drag a control into a new location. This will create a copy with the **same event handler**, i.e. add an event handler to already existing one. This is the behavior you are seeing.

I'd be interested to know the official reference about this behavior, found the above by experiment. I've used CTRL + drag copy method 95% of the time, and had the same question for quite a while. Fortunately, there is a quick fix for event wiring - read below.

*If you used the wrong method, you can manually delete the wiring code (the second handles clause), then double-click the button in question to create new click event handler for it (not a big deal).*

Comment: Thanks - but the "not a big deal" is a big deal, because I always need to edit this since I tend to also use CTRL+drag. I thought there would be an option to configure this behaviour in Visual Studio, but did not found any.

Comment: @user3265070: Using CTRL+C / CTRL+V is not an option? Other than that, I would like to point out that if you are spending so much time copying / pasting and binding your controls, you may need to reconsider your design, i.e. use dynamic binding or some framework with some level of automation for this. From my experience, creating control handlers is 0.01% of development time in a normal workflow.